# Why does MonoDevelop 2.9.4 error when typing D code?

Tags: monodevelop, d

C# code in a C# project is fine. But if I try to type anything into a D project file I get the following error:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Mono.TextEditor.DocumentLine Mono.TextEditor.TextEditorData.GetLine(Int32)'.
   at MonoDevelop.D.Formatting.DTextEditorIndentation.KeyPress(Key key, Char keyChar, ModifierType modifier)
   at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content.TextEditorExtension.KeyPress(Key key, Char keyChar, ModifierType modifier)
   at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content.CompletionTextEditorExtension.KeyPress(Key key, Char keyChar, ModifierType modifier)
   at MonoDevelop.D.DEditorCompletionExtension.KeyPress(Key key, Char keyChar, ModifierType modifier)
   at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content.TextEditorExtension.KeyPress(Key key, Char keyChar, ModifierType modifier)
   at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content.TextEditorExtension.KeyPress(Key key, Char keyChar, ModifierType modifier)
   at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content.TextEditorExtension.KeyPress(Key key, Char keyChar, ModifierType modifier)
   at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content.TextEditorExtension.KeyPress(Key key, Char keyChar, ModifierType modifier)
   at MonoDevelop.SourceEditor.ExtensibleTextEditor.ExtensionKeyPress(Key key, UInt32 ch, ModifierType state)
```

Maybe a bug. Maybe I have a setting wrong.

Comment: Should perhaps this go to the SuperUser.com ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem.
You will need to pull in the latest updates for MonoDevelop (2.9.5) for mono-d to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

The MonoDevelop 2.9.x alphas/betas have many API changes since the 2.8.x stable releases, so third-party addins will need to be ported to work correctly.